# How to link public directory in external Js file

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-5

In my front end side I can show my public directory through "asset." Here when a user hover on the image it should show other image what I have shown through external JS file. But in external Js file I can't indicate public directory through Asset. How do I do that?

```
  <a href="https://www.facebook.com/" target="_blank">
                <img id="facebook-icon" src="{{asset('frontEnd/images/icon/facebook-icon.svg')}}">
    </a>
```

//  `External Js file`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#facebook-icon').hover(function(){
            $(this).attr('src','images/icon/facebook-hover-icon.svg');
            }, function(){
            $(this).attr('src','images/icon/facebook-icon.svg');
        });
     });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define in your layout (header if possible), your base url in javascript, like this :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var BASE_URL = {!! json_encode(url('/')) !!}
</script>
```

So now you can do this in every js file linked after this :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#facebook-icon').hover(function(){
            $(this).attr('src',BASE_URL+'images/icon/facebook-hover-icon.svg');
            }, function(){
            $(this).attr('src',BASE_URL+'images/icon/facebook-icon.svg');
        });
     });
```

Or whatever you want to do that need the base url of your site.

Answer (score 0):

here is a catch

you can use absolute path to achieve this.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#facebook-icon').hover(function(){
        $(this).attr('src','http://www.example.com/images/icon/facebook-hover-icon.svg');
        }, function(){
        $(this).attr('src','http://www.example.com/images/icon/facebook-icon.svg');
    });
 });
```